# React useState Error TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am bouncing into this error while trying to change the name property of a file that is stored in one of my states. I have seen other threads with this same issue but none of them quite relates to hooks or this particular scenario.

My function is quite simple:

```
  const handleNewTitle = async (id) => {
    try {
      const updatedTitles = await [...images].map((image) => {
        if (image.id === id) {
          image.name = editingText;
        }
        return image;
      });
      setImages(updatedTitles);
      setUploadImages(updatedTitles);
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };
```

and this is my JSX

```
          {titleEditing === image.id ? (
            <>
              <input
                className="title-editing-input"
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setEditingText(e.target.value)}
                value={editingText}
                style={{
                  display: typeof image !== "string" ? "block" : "none",
                }}
              />
              <button
                style={{
                  display: typeof image !== "string" ? "block" : "none",
                }}
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  handleNewTitle(image.id);
                }}
              >
                Save New Title
              </button>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <p imgName={i} className="watchface-p">
                {image.name}
              </p>
              <button
                style={{
                  display: typeof image !== "string" ? "block" : "none",
                }}
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  setTitleEditing(image.id);
                }}
              >
                Edit Title
              </button>
            </>
          )}
```

I am not using strict and but I am storing the state in a parent component. Has anyone bumped into this kind of scenario before?

Comment: where does the error appear?

Comment: it appears on this line: image.name = editingText;

Comment: and what is `images`?

Comment: Images is an array of objects where I store some files that I will upload to my DB. each obj looks like this:

File

id: 0.7288769173604276

lastModified: 1629110325000

name: "Screenshot 2021-08-16 at 12.38.39.png"

size: 143276

type: "image/png"

webkitRelativePath: "random images/Screenshot 2021-08-16 at

Comment: @Jacopo Please send error message

Comment: Here it is:
TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.

(anonymous function) — Watchfaces.js:105
map

(anonymous function) — Watchfaces.js:102
asyncFunctionResume

onClick — Watchfaces.js:165
 ......

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with the below approach, hope this will be able to help somebody in the future since there are a lot of threads with the related error message floating around.
As said above, the async approach is not necessary but it helped me keeping track of the error I was getting and debug process.

```
const handleNewTitle = async (id) => {
    try {
      setImages(
        images.map((image) => {
          if (image.id === id) {
            return { ...image, name: editingText };
          } else return image;
        })
      );
      setUploadImages(
        uploadImages.map((image) => {
          if (image.id === id) {
            return { ...image, name: editingText };
          } else return image;
        })
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };
```